# Do I need to import a certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority into a keystore?

Tags: java, ssl

I have been practicing creating self-signed certificates and making a request to an api over https.

I used webclient and netty ssl context, I imported the certificate into cacerts and a keystore in resources, and it worked.

But if a third party app uses a certificate signed by a CA, do I need to do this? Can I simply use webclient.baseUrl(https://....), and then make requests? Will the OS and Java handle the rest?

Comment: Yes, assuming that CA has been imported into your trusted authorities you will not have to do anything special.  The major CAs are included with java in its cacerts file; if you are unsure if you have the CA for whichever client you're calling, get a hold of the certificate and verify the CA exists in `jre/lib/security/cacerts`.  If you're on a mac, I believe this is maintained in the OS' keychain

Comment: Or rather verify that the CA *or one of its signers* exists in the truststore. @lane.maxwell The easiest way to do that is just to try the SSL connection and observe success or failure.